# Should online PDFs be saved as spreads or single pages?

Tags: pdf, page-layout

There are benefits to showing a `pdf` download both as a spread and a single page. Which should I take into account—the view-ability on smaller computer screens or the design appeal of showing them as spreads?

Comment: Good question. Do you have elements which go across the spread?

Comment: I would agree with e100 - depends almost entirely on the layout and how important readability is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take both into account, plus a third consideration: who will be viewing them. Several times I've sent clients PDFs in spreads with first and last being single pages as they would always be in a printed piece, only to have them worry that the page spreads were "too small compared to the first page." After a bit of explanation, they sort of get it, but still aren't sure.

If the idea is that people will download *and print* the pages, then you have to export as single pages. Very few people can print spreads satisfactorily; even fewer know how, even if their equipment is capable of it.

Comment: Good point. Single pages it is.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to take into consideration is that when you have a PDF exported to single pages most (Adobe Reader) PDF viewers supports "spread-view" and you can, while exporting interactive PDF set the default view.

[image]